# How to set static url like http://a.com/js/sso/user.js in Flask

Tags: python, nginx, flask

I have an app using a third party SSO library, one of the imported js would requires /js/sso/user.js file. I've downloaded it in my app dir, the dir tree is like below:

```
.
├── js
│   └── sso
│       └── user.js
├── app.py
└── templates
    └── index.html
```

How should I config my Flask app?

I tried a lot of settings, but it doesn't work.

I'm now using nginx config as a fix, what I actually need a Flask configuration solution.

Comment: So you have some file, that is part of a library that you are using in your application. In this file, there is some HTML code like `<script src="js/sso/user.js">` and you want to make sure this link works? If this is the problem, then you already have solved it correctly by using nginx. If this is not the problem, please add some more details.

Comment: @BurhanKhalid Yes, you got it right! But I'm writing this code as an example, should run on others' machine as easy as possible. Any good idea?

Comment: I do not know what you mean by "run on others' machine" - if its hosted on a server, then you don't have to worry about anything. If you are distributing this application, and you want to take advantage of flask's static file serving then you have to modify the code in the third party application's static files; so the user just has to type `python app.py` and your application (including any other libraries) will work correctly.

Comment: @BurhanKhalid I would like to set it as static file which can be linked by /js/sso/user.js, but I don't know how to setup flask to be like this.